# insert multiple rows at a matching value

Tags: python, pandas

Using Pandas, I want to insert multiple rows for a given matching id `matchid`.

Meaning, I currently string together a list of results and insert at a given row in an existing DF:

```
matchid  |  events_categories 
-----------------------------
0           event_a, event_b, event_c
1           event_b
```

What I want is, for a given matching `matchid` row, insert multiple rows in between:

```
matchid  |  events_categories 
-----------------------------
0           event_a
0           event_b
0           event_c
1           event_b
```

I'm using a `matchid` because the results coming back are from an async request. The values aren't guaranteed in order. So I'm mapping the response object back to the dataframe row.

Python:

```
rs = (grequests.get(u, headers=headers, hooks={'response': 
add_filename_to_response}) for u in urls)
results = grequests.map(rs, exception_handler=exception_handler)

for event_obj in results:
    jsonObj = event_obj.json()
    categories = []
    try:
        for res in jsonObj['results']:
            categories.append(res['category'])
            ### How can I insert at the given row here?
            ### "df.loc[df['matchid']==event_obj.matchid, 'event_categories'] = res['category']" overwrites each value

    except: None

    ### Pair the row to the event_obj via mapping_key

    df.loc[df['matchid']==event_obj.matchid, 'event_categories'] = ', '.join(str(x) for x in categories)

...


'''
In the AJAX response callback, add additional meta data to the response object
'''
def add_filename_to_response(response, *args, **kwargs):
    ### Get filepath from the ?filepath= param in the URL string
    obj_matchid = response.url.split('matchid=')[1].split('&')[0]
    ### Append mapping key to AJAX response object
    response.matchid = obj_matchid

    return response
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is unnest

```
s=df['events_categories'].str.split(',')
pd.DataFrame({'matchid':df['matchid'].repeat(s.str.len()),'events_categories':np.concatenate(s.values)})
Out[517]: 
  events_categories  matchid
0           event_a        0
0           event_b        0
0           event_c        0
1           event_b        1
```

Comment: So you're saying I should append the stringified array to the row first, then in a separate step split them? I can't do that at the initial `append` stage in the loop?

Comment: @Growler why not store them in list , then build the dataframe  outside the loop ?

Comment: Getting error `Cannot cast array data from dtype('float64') to dtype('int64') according to the rule 'safe'`.

Comment: @Growler I check with your sample data , I did not received any error .

Comment: @Growler try this `df.set_index('matchid')['events_categories'].str.split(sep=',').apply(pd.Series).stack()` received the error again ?

Comment: I get `TypeError: split() got an unexpected keyword argument 'sep'` — so I tried without `split(sep=',')` and just did `split(',')`. This threw no errors. But, doing `df.set_index('matchid')['event_categories'].str.split(',').apply(pd.Series).stack()`, then printing `df`, I get the same comma-separated string per row in the dataframe as I originally had.

Comment: @Growler my mistake I think you have blank here , change `',' to ', '`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177601/discussion-between-growler-and-wen).